# Нужно передать данные из связанного списка в таблицу

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

Всем привет мне нужно передать данные из связанного списка в таблицу в базе данных
Вот код с созданием селекта:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.2.1.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".country").change(function(){
var id = $(".country").val();
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "command.php",
data: {id: id},
success: function(data) {
$(".command").html(data);
}
});
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select size='1' class="country">
<option value="0">--Your country--</option>
<?php
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `country`");
while($row = $query->fetch()) {
echo "<option value='{$row->id}'>".$row->title."</option>";
}
?>
```

Вот код с созданием command.php:

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('select[name="command"]').change(function() {
alert($('select[name="command"]').val());
});
});
</script>
<?php
require_once 'connect_bd.php';
if(isset($_POST['id']) && !empty($_POST['id'])) {
$id = intval($_POST['id']);
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `region` WHERE `id_contry` = $id");
echo "<select name='command'>";
while($row = $query->fetch()) {
echo "<option>{$row->title}</option>";
}
echo "</select>";

$country = strip_tags(trim($_POST['country']));
$region = strip_tags(trim($_POST['region']));
mysqli_query($link, " INSERT INTO users_list(country, region)
VALUES ('$country','$region')
");
echo $country";
}
else {
echo "<select name='command' disabled><option value='0'>--Your region--</option></select>";
}
?>
```

Вот код передачи данных с формы:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
      $name = strip_tags(trim($_POST['name']));
      $email = strip_tags(trim($_POST['email']));
      $number = strip_tags(trim($_POST['number']));
      $country = strip_tags(trim($_POST['country']));
      $region = strip_tags(trim($_POST['region']));
      $time = $_POST['time'];

      mysqli_query($link, " INSERT INTO users_list(name, email, number, country, region, time)
                    VALUES ('$name','$email','$number','$country','$region', '$time')
      ");
    }
    if(empty($_POST['name']) == TRUE) {
      if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
      $nameError = "Your name is not correct: <br>";
      echo $nameError;
      } else {
        $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
      }
      if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
        $emailError = "Your email is not correct:: <br>";
        echo $emailError;
      } else {
        $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
      }
      if (empty($_POST["number"])) {
        $numberError = "Your number is not correct: <br>";
        echo $numberError;
      } else {
        $number = test_input($_POST["number"]);
      }
    }
```

Мне нужно чтобы при заполнении формы данные из селектов передавались в отдельную таблицу с данными. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

Comment: а чем отличаются первый и второй код?

Comment: во втором условие если заполнено первое поле тогда можна заполнить второе иначе второе поле не доступно